# COM BCS model programmatic creation methods

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, bcs

Following the source code found here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Creating-SharePoint-2010-ad694d17

I've managed to create the Create, Update and Delete method, but only the Delete operation works in the external list.

Here is the code snippet:

```
            // create the delete method
            Method getDeleteMethod = customerEntity.Methods.Create("DeleteCustomer", true, false, "DeleteCustomer");

            // specify the query and command type
            getDeleteMethod.Properties.Add("RdbCommandText", "DELETE FROM [tblCustomer] where [Customer ID] = @CustomerID");
            getDeleteMethod.Properties.Add("RdbCommandType", "Text");

            // create the Customer return parameter
            Parameter DeleteIDParameter = getDeleteMethod.Parameters.Create("@CustomerID", true, DirectionType.In);


            // create the TypeDescriptor for the CustomerID parameter
            DeleteIDParameter.CreateRootTypeDescriptor(new TypeDescriptorParams(standardStringType)
            {
                Name = "CustomerID",
                IdentifierReference = customerIdentifierRef,
                MetadataCatalog = catalog
            });

            getDeleteMethod.MethodInstances.Create(getDeleteMethod.Name, true, null,
                MethodInstanceType.Deleter, true);


            //end delete


            //update method
            // create the update method
            Method getUpdateMethod = customerEntity.Methods.Create("UpdateCustomer", true, false, "UpdateCustomer");

            // specify the query and command type
            getUpdateMethod.Properties.Add("RdbCommandText", "UPDATE [tblCustomer] SET [Company Name] = @CompanyName WHERE [Customer ID] = @CustomerID");
            getUpdateMethod.Properties.Add("RdbCommandType", "Text");

            // create the Customer return parameter
            Parameter UpdateIDParameter = getUpdateMethod.Parameters.Create("@CustomerID", true, DirectionType.In);
            Parameter UpdateIDParameter2 = getUpdateMethod.Parameters.Create("@CompanyName", true, DirectionType.In);
            // create the TypeDescriptor for the CustomerID parameter
            //IEntityReference coyname = customerEntityRef;
            UpdateIDParameter.CreateRootTypeDescriptor(new TypeDescriptorParams(standardStringType)
            {
                Name = "CustomerID",
                IdentifierReference = customerIdentifierRef,
                MetadataCatalog = catalog

            });
            UpdateIDParameter2.CreateRootTypeDescriptor(new TypeDescriptorParams(standardStringType)
            {
                Name = "CompanyName"
            });

            getUpdateMethod.MethodInstances.Create(getUpdateMethod.Name, true, null,
                 MethodInstanceType.Updater, true);

            //end update


            //insert method

            // create the insert method
            Method getInsertMethod = customerEntity.Methods.Create("InsertCustomer", true, false, "InsertCustomer");

            // specify the query and command type
            getInsertMethod.Properties.Add("RdbCommandText", "INSERT INTO [tblCustomer] ([Customer ID], [Company Name]) VALUES (@CustomerID,  @CompanyName)");
            getInsertMethod.Properties.Add("RdbCommandType", "Text");

            // create the Customer return parameter
            Parameter InsertIDParameter = getInsertMethod.Parameters.Create("@CustomerID", true, DirectionType.In);
            Parameter InsertIDParameter2 = getInsertMethod.Parameters.Create("@CompanyName", true, DirectionType.In);

            // create the TypeDescriptor for the CustomerID parameter
            InsertIDParameter.CreateRootTypeDescriptor(new TypeDescriptorParams(standardStringType)
            {
                Name = "CustomerID",
                IdentifierReference = customerIdentifierRef,
                MetadataCatalog = catalog
            });

            InsertIDParameter2.CreateRootTypeDescriptor(new TypeDescriptorParams(standardStringType)
            {
                Name = "CompanyName",
                MetadataCatalog = catalog
            });

            // create the Customer return parameter
            Parameter insertParameter = getInsertMethod.Parameters.Create("tblCustomer", true, DirectionType.Return);

            TypeDescriptorParams returnElementTypeInsertDescriptorParams =
                new TypeDescriptorParams
                {
                    Name = "tblCustomer",
                    IsCached = true,
                    Type = typeof(IDbTransaction),
                    Flags = TypeDescriptorFlags.None,
                };

            TypeDescriptorParams returnCollectionTypeInsertDescriptorParams =
                new TypeDescriptorParams(returnElementTypeInsertDescriptorParams)
                {

                    Type = typeof(IDataRecord),
                    Flags = TypeDescriptorFlags.IsCollection,
                    MetadataCatalog = catalog
                };

            // create the TypeDescriptors for the Customer return parameter
            TypeDescriptor returInsertTypeDescriptor =
                insertParameter.CreateRootTypeDescriptor(returnCollectionTypeInsertDescriptorParams);

            TypeDescriptor returnElementInsertTypeDescriptor =
                returInsertTypeDescriptor.CreateChildTypeDescriptor(returnElementTypeInsertDescriptorParams);
            //returnElementInsertTypeDescriptor.Delete();
            returnElementInsertTypeDescriptor.CreateChildTypeDescriptor(new TypeDescriptorParams(standardStringType)
            {
                Name = "Customer ID",
                IdentifierReference = customerIdentifierRef,
            });

            returnElementInsertTypeDescriptor.CreateChildTypeDescriptor(new TypeDescriptorParams(standardStringType)
            {
                Name = "Company Name"
            });



            getInsertMethod.MethodInstances.Create(getInsertMethod.Name, true, returnElementInsertTypeDescriptor,
                MethodInstanceType.Creator, true);

            //end insert
```

I can't find any examples similar to this approach that I'am using. I would gladly appreciate any input if anyone knows how to do the Update and Create method!? Thanks